# Hibernate doesn't fetch eager

Tags: java, hibernate

I have tow classes, the "Article" which contains a @ManyToOne reference to a "SurchargeGroup" which specifies the surcharge for that article.

```
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(doNotUseGetters = true)
@Audited
public final class Article {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
  @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
  @Getter(onMethod_ = {@Key(PermissionKey.ARTICLE_ID_READ)})
  @Setter(onMethod_ = {@Key(PermissionKey.ARTICLE_ID_WRITE)})
  private int id;


  @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
  @ManyToOne
  @Getter(onMethod_ = {@Key(PermissionKey.SURCHARGE_TABLE_SUPPLIER_READ)})
  @Setter(onMethod_ = {@Key(PermissionKey.SURCHARGE_TABLE_SUPPLIER_WRITE)})
  private SurchargeGroup surchargeGroup;

}
```

The other class "SurchargeGroup" contains a parent object reference which can inherit the surcharge to the "SurchargeGroup" if it isn't set the case that no surcharge is provided by any parent is not possible.

```
@Table
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode(doNotUseGetters = true)
@Audited
public class SurchargeGroup implements Serializable, Cloneable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column
  @Getter(onMethod_ = {@Key(PermissionKey.SURCHARGE_TABLE_ID_READ)})
  @Setter(onMethod_ = {@Key(PermissionKey.SURCHARGE_TABLE_ID_WRITE)})
  private int id;

  @Column
  @Setter(onMethod_ = {@Key(PermissionKey.SURCHARGE_TABLE_SURCHARGE_WRITE)})
  private Double surcharge;

  @Column
  @Getter(onMethod_ = {@Key(PermissionKey.SURCHARGE_TABLE_NAME_READ)})
  @Setter(onMethod_ = {@Key(PermissionKey.SURCHARGE_TABLE_NAME_WRITE)})
  private String name;

  @JoinColumn
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @Getter(onMethod_ = {@Key(PermissionKey.SURCHARGE_TABLE_SUPPLIER_READ)})
  @Setter(onMethod_ = {@Key(PermissionKey.SURCHARGE_TABLE_SUPPLIER_WRITE)})
  private SurchargeGroup parent;

  public double getSurcharge() {
    if (surcharge == null) {
      return parent == null
          ? supplier == null
              ? Setting.SURCHARGE_DEFAULT.getDoubleValue()
              : supplier.getDefaultSurcharge()
          : parent.getSurcharge();
    } else return surcharge;
  }

 @JoinColumn
  @ManyToOne
  @Getter(onMethod_ = {@Key(PermissionKey.SURCHARGE_TABLE_SUPPLIER_READ)})
  @Setter(onMethod_ = {@Key(PermissionKey.SURCHARGE_TABLE_SUPPLIER_WRITE)})
  private Supplier supplier;
}
```

My problem is now that if I call the "getSurcharge()" method I get this exception which I cannot explain to myself because I marked the surcharge group to fetch eager

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy [kernbeisser.DBEntities.SurchargeGroup#1046] - the owning Session was closed
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:172)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:309)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor.intercept(ByteBuddyInterceptor.java:45)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.ProxyConfiguration$InterceptorDispatcher.intercept(ProxyConfiguration.java:95)
    at kernbeisser.DBEntities.SurchargeGroup$HibernateProxy$cdTAuBkS.getSurcharge(Unknown Source)
```

I asked myself if this could get caused by the @Audited annotation? Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Note: the @Key annotations have no effect to this scenario.

Here is what the debugger shows (Sorry for the German toString() functions):
[image: This is what the debugger shows]

Comment: What makes you think that the problem is loading the `parent`? What happens if you try to access the `name` or `surcharge` fields?

Comment: @tgdavies I've added the Debbuger infos thats why I thought that

Comment: OK, looks convincing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate needs to stop eagerly fetching associations at some point, otherwise it would need to join an infinite number of times the `SurchargeGroup` entity (since it references itself).

The depth these fetches can be controlled application wide using the `hibernate.max_fetch_depth` property.

Answer (score 0):

The source of the error was the **AuditReader** it doesn't fetch all eager properties even if they are annotated as **Fetch.EAGER**
It looks like the **AuditReader** only fetches **one level** of eager relations:

Article -> SurchargeGroup ->  SurchargeGroup -> ...
(fetched)  (fetched)          (not fetched)